export 'ethers'.'provider' (imported as 'ethers') was not found in 'ethers'
export 'ethers'.'provider' (imported as 'ethers') was not found in 'ethers' (possible exports: AbiCoder, AbstractProvider, AbstractSigner, AlchemyProvider, AnkrProvider, BaseContract, BaseWallet, Block, BrowserProvider, CloudflareProvider, ConstructorFragment, Contract, ContractEventPayload, ContractFactory, ContractTransactionReceipt, ContractTransactionResponse, ContractUnknownEventPayload, EnsPlugin, EnsResolver, ErrorDescription, ErrorFragment, EtherSymbol, EtherscanPlugin, EtherscanProvider, EventFragment, EventLog, EventPayload, FallbackFragment, FallbackProvider, FeeData, FeeDataNetworkPlugin, FetchCancelSignal, FetchRequest, FetchResponse, FetchUrlFeeDataNetworkPlugin, FixedNumber, Fragment, FunctionFragment, GasCostPlugin, HDNodeVoidWallet, HDNodeWallet, Indexed, InfuraProvider, InfuraWebSocketProvider, Interface, IpcSocketProvider, JsonRpcApiProvider, JsonRpcProvider, JsonRpcSigner, LangEn, Log, LogDescription, MaxInt256, MaxUint256, MessagePrefix, MinInt256, Mnemonic, MulticoinProviderPlugin, N, NamedFragment, Network, NetworkPlugin, NonceManager, ParamType, PocketProvider, QuickNodeProvider, Result, Signature, SigningKey, SocketBlockSubscriber, SocketEventSubscriber, SocketPendingSubscriber, SocketProvider, SocketSubscriber, StructFragment, Transaction, TransactionDescription, TransactionReceipt, TransactionResponse, Typed, TypedDataEncoder, UndecodedEventLog, UnmanagedSubscriber, Utf8ErrorFuncs, VoidSigner, Wallet, WebSocketProvider, WeiPerEther, Wordlist, WordlistOwl, WordlistOwlA, ZeroAddress, ZeroHash, accessListify, assert, assertArgument, assertArgumentCount, assertNormalize, assertPrivate, checkResultErrors, computeAddress, computeHmac, concat, copyRequest, dataLength, dataSlice, decodeBase58, decodeBase64, decodeBytes32String, decodeRlp, decryptCrowdsaleJson, decryptKeystoreJson, decryptKeystoreJsonSync, defaultPath, defineProperties, dnsEncode, encodeBase58, encodeBase64, encodeBytes32String, encodeRlp, encryptKeystoreJson, encryptKeystoreJsonSync, ensNormalize, formatEther, formatUnits, fromTwos, getAccountPath, getAddress, getBigInt, getBytes, getBytesCopy, getCreate2Address, getCreateAddress, getDefaultProvider, getIcapAddress, getIndexedAccountPath, getNumber, getUint, hashMessage, hexlify, id, isAddress, isAddressable, isBytesLike, isCallException, isCrowdsaleJson, isError, isHexString, isKeystoreJson, isValidName, keccak256, lock, makeError, mask, namehash, parseEther, parseUnits, pbkdf2, randomBytes, recoverAddress, resolveAddress, resolveProperties, ripemd160, scrypt, scryptSync, sha256, sha512, showThrottleMessage, solidityPacked, solidityPackedKeccak256, solidityPackedSha256, stripZerosLeft, toBeArray, toBeHex, toBigInt, toNumber, toQuantity, toTwos, toUtf8Bytes, toUtf8CodePoints, toUtf8String, uuidV4, verifyMessage, verifyTypedData, version, wordlists, zeroPadBytes, zeroPadValue)
I had tried to import like this
import ethers from ethers
import {ethers} from ethers
import {providers} from ethers

"I replaced const provider = new ethers.Web3Provider(ethereum); with const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(ethereum);, and it works

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
